# No module named 'json2html'

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

[image]

I checked my PATH, made sure the `json2html` is in the path and that it's installed. Yet, I can't get it to load.

[image]

Comment: are you using anaconda environment?

Comment: Please post the issue directly instead of adding pictures containing the error

Comment: Hi, after installing the package, you may want to close the notebook, close the terminal. And re-open the terminal and your notebook. This may solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for where openpyxl is, since it worked without error. I found it here:

- F:\Users\John\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages

So then I did this:

```
pip3 install --target=F:\Users\John\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages json2html
```

And it worked!

Comment: Please don't add questions to answers. Answers should answer the question at the top of the page. If you have other questions, you can post them separately. Do take the [tour] and read about [ask] and [answer]